# how to disable a scroll bar on a fullscreen slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, scrollbar

I would like to know how to disable a scroll bar on a full screen slider.

There is a scroll down button at each slider. What I would like is that when I click on this button then go to just below slider and show the scroll bar. Otherwise don't show the scrollbar.

I'm looking for a code example.

Comment: Did you try overflow:hidden ?

Comment: http://www.hugeinc.com/ see this link i want to do like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set style to '**overflow:hidden**' on a div or on body on which you don't wan't to scroll and remove this when you click on next button.

Comment: it's working but 1 more problem i m facing that when i click on button page go to down and show scrollbar but when i scroll at top, there is showing scrollbar at top., also i don't want scrollbar when i scroll at top

Comment: once your scroll and reach at your required position once again add 'overflow:hidden' on your required div or body and scroll disappear other wise you also manage it via <div> show hide using jquery...

Comment: thank u sir now  my problem is solve thank u so much